# Download page using IE engine + use POST

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, winapi, visual-studio-2012

I need to make web-based API calls, using POST. This is very easily achievable via libcurl, but in my case - it is only working via IE API due to special requirements.

I found winapi function [URLOpenStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775129(v=vs.85).aspx) which is working fine, but I did not found way, to use this function with POST data.

Is there are any way to do so? Or use other function, but it should be strictly IE API based.

Comment: If libcurl works for you, you should keep using it. You can specify a custom `User-Agent` request header via [`CURLOPT_USERAGENT`](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_USERAGENT.html) to make the server think IE is the one requesting the URL. Many servers customize their data based on the `User-Agent` header. If you really want to switch to a Microsoft API then use [WinInet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385331.aspx) (see `HttpSendRequest/Ex()`) or [WinHTTP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384273.aspx) (see `WinHttpSendRequest()`) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using WinINET's (wininet.dll) HttpOpenRequest function instead:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384233(v=vs.85).aspx

I'm not sure what version of C++ you are using but I found a code example here in CodeProject:

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/816567/How-do-I-post-data-using-HttpSendRequest-to-a-loca

Answer (score 0):

I've found "Msxml2.XMLHTTP.6.0" component, which suits me best, JFYI anyone, who will find this question :)